# Radio button always returning "yes" value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using simple radio button, if I select `yes` or `no` option, it always calls the `yes` option.

Below is my code:

```js
$('input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]').change(function() {
  if ($('input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]').val() == 'Yes') {
    alert("yes");
    var dropdownval = $("#dropDownsub").val();
    target_element.removeAttr('href').attr('action', dropdownval);
  }

  if ($('input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]').val() == 'No') {
    alert("no");
    var dropdownval = $("#dropDownsub").val();
    // target_element.removeAttr('href');
    target_element.removeAttr('action').attr('href', $("#edit-link-url .url").val());
    $(event.target).attr("href", $("#edit-link-url .url").val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="int-link" name="selectlinktype" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="href-link" name="selectlinktype" value="No" /> No
```

Select yes or no, it will always go inside `yes` condition, `no` condition is never fired. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting first element with name `selectlinktype` so it's always `yes`. Add `:checked` to your selector to select actual selected element.

```js
$('input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]').change(function(){
  if($('input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]:checked').val() == 'Yes'){
     alert("yes");
     var dropdownval = $("#dropDownsub").val();
     target_element.removeAttr('href').attr('action', dropdownval);
  }
  
  if($('input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]:checked').val() == 'No'){
   alert("no");
    var dropdownval = $("#dropDownsub").val();
   // target_element.removeAttr('href');
    target_element.removeAttr('action').attr('href',$("#edit-link-url .url").val() );
    $(event.target).attr("href" , $("#edit-link-url .url").val()); 
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="int-link"  name="selectlinktype" value="Yes" /> Yes
  <input type="radio" id="href-link"  name="selectlinktype" value="No" /> No
```

Comment: When i am selecting the radio button, `event.target` is selecting the item i clicked, but second time if i click on some other item, it is selecting `last one + this one`, similarly 3rd time all 3...why it is doing so can you help ?

Answer (score 3):

`input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]` will select both of your inputs. Then `.val()` checks for `value` of the first one, which happens to be `"yes"` (due to `value="yes"`).

You need to subselect the input by whether or not it is selected: `input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]:checked`

Alternately you can see what the target of the event was (because typically the change event would originate from the element that was just activated), so that a selector is not needed: use `this` or `event.target`.

Comment: When i am selecting the radio button, `event.target` is selecting the item i clicked, but second time if i click on some other item, it is selecting `last one + this one`, similarly 3rd time all 3...why it is doing so can you help ?

Comment: `event.target` can only be one element. Since this doesn't look like a clarification on the current question or answers, you should ask a new question, that correctly reflects your current code.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking value of radio with name selectlinktype but you need to check radio button which is clicked and selected

Also, use `if` and `else if` block instead of two `if`. Use `$(this)` for target element, see below code

```js
 $('input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]').change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value == 'Yes'){
     alert("yes");
     var dropdownval = $("#dropDownsub").val();
     $(this).removeAttr('href').attr('action', dropdownval);
  } else if(value == 'No'){
   alert("no");
    var dropdownval = $("#dropDownsub").val();
   // target_element.removeAttr('href');
    $(this).removeAttr('action').attr('href',$("#edit-link-url .url").val() );
    $(this).attr("href" , $("#edit-link-url .url").val()); 
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="int-link"  name="selectlinktype" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="href-link"  name="selectlinktype" value="No" /> No
```

Comment: When i am selecting the radio button, `event.target` is selecting the item i clicked, but second time if i click on some other item, it is selecting `last one + this one`, similarly 3rd time all 3...why it is doing so can you help ?

Comment: In this case, use `click` event and not `change` because when you select another radio button then previous one radio button's change event will fire as it is changing value. Use `$('input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]').click(function(){`

Comment: the problem is still the same

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue on code snippet or jsfiddle and pass me the link so that i can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Your current selector is matching both the radio buttons. Either use `:checked` as part of the selector or `this` to target the current radio:

```js
$('input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]').change(function(e){
  console.clear();
  console.log(e.target);
  if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){
     alert("yes");
     //var dropdownval = $("#dropDownsub").val();
     //target_element.removeAttr('href').attr('action', dropdownval);
  }  
  else if($(this).val() == 'No'){
   alert("no");
    //var dropdownval = $("#dropDownsub").val();
    //target_element.removeAttr('href');
    //target_element.removeAttr('action').attr('href',$("#edit-link-url .url").val() );
    //$(event.target).attr("href" , $("#edit-link-url .url").val()); 
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="int-link"  name="selectlinktype" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="href-link"  name="selectlinktype" value="No" /> No
```

Comment: When i am selecting the radio button, `event.target` is selecting the item i clicked, but second time if i click on some other item, it is selecting `last one + this one`, similarly 3rd time all 3...why it is doing so can you help ?

Comment: @user2828442, I don't know in which context you are getting that. But in any context it should not select the previous one. I have shown the the target in console in my updated answer.....please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it with click event

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="int-link"  name="radio_name" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="href-link"  name="radio_name" value="No" /> No

<script>
$('input:radio[name="radio_name"]').click(function(){
  var radio_val = $(this).val()
  if(radio_val == 'Yes'){
     alert("yes");
  }  
  else if(radio_val == 'No'){
   alert("no");
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('input:radio[name="selectlinktype"]').change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value == 'Yes'){
     alert("yes");
     var dropdownval = $("#dropDownsub").val();
     $(this).removeAttr('href').attr('action', dropdownval);
  } else if(value == 'No'){
   alert("no");
    var dropdownval = $("#dropDownsub").val();
   // target_element.removeAttr('href');
    $(this).removeAttr('action').attr('href',$("#edit-link-url .url").val() );
    $(this).attr("href" , $("#edit-link-url .url").val()); 
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="int-link"  name="selectlinktype" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="href-link"  name="selectlinktype" value="No" /> No
```